# How use Affix component in Twitter Bootstrap 2.1.1

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to use affix component in latest version of twitter bootstrap by following [documented steps](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#affix) and I can't get it work. Here is the example in [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NRhv8/13/)

I see two problems

- Clicking sidenav links scrolls correctly to appropriate content, but scrolling content doesn't make appropriate sidenav link active
- The sidenav is not styled as in bootstrap [website](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#affix).

I would appreciate if someone helps to get this working as in twitter bootstrap site.

Comment: For the first issue, I think you have to manually set the link's class to 'active' when clicked.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are looking for a ScrollSpy. It highlights a menu item as you scroll or switch to the appropriate section.

Affix is in some way alternative to experimental CSS `position:sticky`. What it does that changes menu `position` from `static` to `fixed` as you scroll *n* px from the top.

Answer (score 4):

The documentation about affix is confusing because it describes the affix saying "The subnavigation on the left is a live demo of the affix plugin." whereas this subnavigation is even more an example of the scrollspy.

I resembled the subnavigation like on the bootstrap docu into a small jsfiddle at

http://jsfiddle.net/citykid/Gb2SD/6/

```
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="span2" id="navparent">
                <ul class="nav nav-list navex" data-spy="affix">
                    <li><a href="#o">overview</a>
                    </li>
                    ...
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="span9">
                <p>top of the document</p>
                 <h3 id="o" data-offset-top="200">Overview</h3>
                <div style="height:500px">dummy content overview</div>
                ...
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script src="/js/jquery-1.9.0.js"></script>
    <script src="http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/assets/js/bootstrap-scrollspy.js"></script>
    <script src="http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/assets/js/bootstrap-affix.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $(document.body).scrollspy({
                target: "#navparent"
            });
        });
    </script>
</body>
```

Use the JS api, not the data attributes, otherwise you encounter a bug described at jsfiddle.net/citykid/Gb2SD/4